# Is usage of Fcntl flock() reliable for handling mutex? [PERL]

Tags: perl, mutex, flock

I created a perl script as below - (Showing only relevant code snippets)

```
#!/appl/pm/vendor/perl/lx-x86/5.14.2/bin/perl -w
my $no_of_retries = 60;
my $sleep_time = 60;

use Fcntl qw(:flock SEEK_END);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# To allow only one instance loader program to run
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sub SyncWaitForFile($$$) {
my ($delay_file, $no_of_retries, $sleep_time) = @_;

#check for delay file
my $minutes_passed = 0;

while ( (-e $delay_file) && (--$no_of_retries) && ($no_of_retries > 0) )
{
    if ( (($minutes_passed / 10) == 0) && ($minutes_passed != 0)) # Check Every 10 minutes and send mail
    {
        MailNotify ("Loader with [PID=$$;hostname=$host;user=$ENV{'LOGNAME'}] is waiting for $minutes_passed minutes for delay file to be removed", "Delay File => $delay_file", $maillist);
    }
    Logger::info ("Waiting for removal of delay_file $delay_file for $sleep_time seconds. Time passed waiting => $minutes_passed minutes. Number of retries remaining : $no_of_retries");
    sleep($sleep_time);
    ++$minutes_passed;
}

if ($no_of_retries <= 0)
{
    MailNotify ("Loader with [PID=$$;hostname=$host;user=$ENV{'LOGNAME'}] has exited due to non-removal of delay file", "Delay File => $delay_file", $maillist);
    ErrorExit("Couldn't Acquire Exclusive Lock. loader.pl cannot run in parallel. So Exiting", 1, 0);
}

while(1)
{
    my $flockfile = "${delay_file}.flockFile";
    open (my $handle, ">" , $flockfile) or ErrorExit("Not able to open file $flockfile", -1, 0);

    Logger::info  "Acquiring lock on $flockfile";
    flock($handle, LOCK_EX) or ErrorExit("Failed during lock", -1, 0); #Take the lock

    #Check again for delay file as while the time this process took the lock,
    #by that time some other process may took lock  created the delay file and release the lock
    if (-e $delay_file)
    {
        Logger::info  "Releasing lock on $flockfile";
        flock($handle, LOCK_UN); # Unlocks the delay file

        # Wait till this delay_file is removed
        Logger::info "Waiting for removal of delay_file $delay_file";
        while ( (-e $delay_file) && (--$no_of_retries) && ($no_of_retries > 0) )
        {
            if ( (($minutes_passed / 10) == 0) && ($minutes_passed != 0) )
            {
                MailNotify ("Loader with [PID=$$;hostname=$host;user=$ENV{'LOGNAME'}] is waiting for $minutes_passed minutes for delay file to be removed", "Delay File => $delay_file", $maillist);
            }
            Logger::info ("Waiting for removal of delay_file $delay_file for $sleep_time seconds. Time passed waiting => $minutes_passed. Number of retries remaining : $no_of_retries");
            sleep($sleep_time);
            ++$minutes_passed;
        }

        if ($no_of_retries <= 0)
        {
            MailNotify ("Loader with [PID=$$;hostname=$host;user=$ENV{'LOGNAME'}] has exited due to non-removal of delay file", "Delay File => $delay_file", $maillist);
            ErrorExit("Couldn't Acquire Exclusive Lock. loader.pl cannot run in parallel. So Exiting", -1, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            next;
        }
    }

    Logger::info "Creating delay file $delay_file";
    open (DELAY_FILE, "> $delay_file") or ErrorExit("ERROR: Unable to open file:$delay_file $!", -1, 0);
    print DELAY_FILE "Locked by Loader with [PID=$$;hostname=$host;user=$ENV{'LOGNAME'}]\n";
    close(DELAY_FILE); 
    Logger::info  "Releasing lock on $flockfile";
    flock($handle, LOCK_UN); # Unlocks the flock file
    last;
}}
```

The above code fails under stress test.
I ran 25 parallel instances and it was working fine.

But when the system reached more than 50 parallel instances, waiting for the delay_file to get free, it got blocked.
Most of the loaders failed at the following line -

```
flock($handle, LOCK_EX) or ErrorExit("Failed during lock", -1, 0);
```

**I have just two questions -**

[1] **What could have been the possible reason for failure when load increased ?** (It wasn't failing when the load was less)

[2] **What is the best way to handle mutex in PERL so that it works even under excessive load?**

I am using PERL on Linux -

PERL  - **5.14.2**

Linux - **RHEL Server 5.11**

Comment: re 1) check what says $! `ErrorExit("Failed during lock: $!" ..`

Comment: You must never use subroutine prototypes in Perl. They are for a very different purpose than prototypes in other languages, and don't do any type checking or parameter verification at all. Just `sub SyncWaitForFile { ... }` is correct.

Comment: @Сухой27, I am not able to reproduce the bug again. It just failed once, miserably. Since I was working on production support, I had to revert back the changes done to the script and avoid flock logic altogether.

But still, I am curious to know as to why it may have failed.

Comment: @Borodin, I am pretty sure that prototyping is not causing any issue as of now. ;) (Still thanks for the suggestion).